# Filter query by dates in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

Each month I need to filter the dates of views to get quarterly data. In other queries I've seen the use of a table with Beginning and Ending dates that a user can select once which other views can reference in the WHERE clause, bypassing the need to change the dates manually. I'm not sure if this is will cause performance issues or if it is an inefficient method. Either way, for queries that have outer joins this approach does not work. Below is an example of the code that produces the error (not the actual tables or code I'm working with but same problem):

```
SELECT performer.firstname, 
       performer.lastname, 
       Sum(score.points) AS SumOfPoints 
FROM   rundates, 
       (performer 
        LEFT JOIN score 
               ON performer.performerid = score.performerid) 
       INNER JOIN show 
               ON ( show.performerid = score.performerid ) 
                  AND ( show.episodenumber = score.episodenumber ) 
                  AND ( show.seasonnumber = score.seasonnumber ) 
                  AND ( performer.performerid = show.performerid ) 
WHERE  (( ( show.airdate ) BETWEEN [rundates].[begindate] AND 
                                   [rundates].[enddate] )) 
GROUP  BY performer.firstname, 
          performer.lastname;
```

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to do filter besides turning the above to a sub-query
   then doing the WHERE clause on the sub-query?
2. Is there a standard way to filter multiple views by a date range besides changing the BETWEEN criteria for each that could apply for all queries other than the table method stated above?
3. Is the table method a bad code writing that will cause issues later?

Comment: MS Access has weird rules about inequalities in `JOIN` predicates.  Your method of doing this is fine for that database.  Is there a "standard way"?  In most databases, you would put the join condition in the `ON` clause where it belongs.  You might consider upgrading to another (free) database, such as SQL Server Express.

Comment: I don't see anything that specifies a specific record, or set of records,  in the rundates table.

Comment: @DanBracuk in the rundates table it has two dates that a user can pick from using a date picker so that other queries can use it in the criteria for the WHERE clause. For example, if I am requested to pull Q4 2015 data, I would change the two dates in the rundates table to '10/1/2015' and '12/31/2015'; the begindate and enddate, respectively. Currently, this is the approach being used to mange the WHERE clause since there are about 25 different views that need date criteria specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH 
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -3, @mydate), 0) AS StartOfThreeMonthsBack,
       DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @mydate), 0) AS StartOfCurrentMonth 
AS BOUNDARIES

SELECT <your select>
FROM <your table>, BOUNDARIES
WHERE...
  AND <date from your field> >= BOUNDARIES.StartOfThreeMonthsBack
  AND <date from your field> <  BOUNDARIES.StartOfCurrentMonth
```

Sorry no tool to test it, but this is the idea